# Joint CDF's of both continuous and discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am working on some homework and have arrived at a problem that has me stumped. I am trying to find the conditional probability of Y given a discrete variable X or:
$$F_{Y|X}(y)$$ which I know is equal to:
$$
F_{Y|X}(y) = \frac{ \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y, X = x)}{\mathbb{P}(X = x)}=\frac{F_{Y,X}(y,x)}{\mathbb{P}(X=x)}
$$
In the problem we are given that X is a random variable representing a dice roll and that Y is a continuous random variable that is distributed exponential with parameter *X*.

My first thought was to sum , to the given x value, the exponential distribution of Y with the corresponding value of X:

$$\sum_{i=1}^x 1-e^{(-iy)}$$

However this gave me a super nasty looking partial sum:
$$\frac{(e^{(-(1+x) y)} (e^y+e^{((2+x) y)} x-e^{((1+x) y)} (1+x)))}{(-1+e^y)}$$
which does not look right.

Next I thought about trying to find the conditional probability with a given X. This lead to me to try:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)*F_{Y|X}(y, X=x)= \frac{1}{6}*(1-e^{-xy})$$
This formula, however limited the values I could get to ~.1666 for any value of y.

I am not looking for a complete answer but if anyone could help me correct my thinking that would be great, thanks!

Comment: It looks like the problem is a lot easier than you are trying to make it be.  If  random variate $y$ is chosen by rolling a discrete uniform random $x$ on $[1,6]$ and then  finding $y$ by an exponential distribution with mean $x$, then the conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$ is just that exponential distribution (using that value of $x$ as the mean).

Comment: So my second answer would be more correct, the conditional probability would just be without the 1/6. Would that make what I have written in my second answer actually be the joint CDF of the two variables then?

Answer (score 1):

I think you first answer reverses what you want.

You could say $$\displaystyle F_Y(y) = \sum_x \mathbb{P}(X=x) F_{Y|X=x}(y)$$  and possibly even turn this into a density $\displaystyle f_Y(y) = \sum_x \mathbb{P}(X=x) f_{Y|X=x}(y)$

So your particular example would give $\displaystyle F_Y(y) = 1 - \tfrac16(e^{-y}+e^{-2y}+e^{-3y}+e^{-4y}+e^{-5y}+e^{-6y})=1-\frac{e^{-y}(1-e^{-6y} )}{6(1-e^{-y})}$